# Error extending PDO class

Tags: php

In this code I try to extendo PDO

```
class mypdo extends PDO{

    static public $db = null;

    public function __construct($dsn, $username=false, $password=false){
        if(self::$db==null){
            try {            
                self::$db = parent::__construct($dsn, $username, $password);
                self::$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
              die("PDO CONNECTION ERROR: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>");
            }
        }
        return self::$db;
    }
}
```

when I call

```
$db = new mypdo(<here my DSN>,<here my user>,<here my password>);
```

I get this error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setAttribute() on a non-object

the error is in this line

```
self::$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

`setAttribute()` is a Method of PDO object, Why this error?

when I add this method to the class my PDO

```
public function lastInsertId($name) {
    return self::$db->lastInsertId($name); 
}
```

if I try to call it I get the same error message

I think the correct code is

```
class mypdo extends PDO{

    static public $db = null;

    public function __construct($dsn, $username=false, $password=false){
        if(self::$db==null){
            try {            
                parent::__construct($dsn, $username, $password);
                parent::setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
              die("PDO CONNECTION ERROR: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>");
            }
        }
        return self::$db;
    }

    public function runSQL($SQL) {
        return parent::exec($SQL);
    }

    public function lastInsertId($name) {
       return parent::lastInsertId($name);
    } 

}
```

Comment: Try self::$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password); instead of self::$db = parent::__construct($dsn, $username, $password);

Answer (score 3):

In PHP, it's common practice for object constructors, in this case `PDO`, to not return values.

When you're doing the following:

```
self::$db = parent::__construct($dsn, $username, $password);
```

if the `PDO` constructor (`parent::__construct()`) isn't returning a value, you're setting `self::$db` to a `null`-value. This would be why you're receiving the error *"Call to member function `setAttribute()` on a non-object"*, because `null` is not an object.

To test, you could try the following:

```
parent::__construct($dsn, $username, $password);
self::$db = $this;
```

This will call the parent's constructor and then set the `self::$db` reference to the current instance.

Comment: could you tell difference between  `self::$db = parent::__construct($dsn, $username, $password);` and yours

Comment: if I try self::$db = parent::__construct($dsn, $username, $password,array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));